# how to insert values into user inputted column using pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

im trying to insert values into a column that a user has asked to be changed which is called `surnamereq` and the user change which is called `name1`. `money_spent` is the name of the table and `first_name` is the column that the user is changing the value of.

This is how it should be written in SQL(i think):

`INSERT INTO money_spent(first_name)
WHERE last_name = surnamereq
VALUES(name1)`

This is what ive got in python:

`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO money_spent(first_name) WHERE last_name = ?, surnamereq VALUES(name1)")`

Thanks

Comment: If you are updating an existing row in the table then you need to use an `UPDATE` statement, not an `INSERT` statement. (`INSERT` is for adding a new row.)

Comment: I have this now:

Comment: `cursor.execute("""
        UPDATE money_spent
        SET first_name = ?, fname
        WHERE last_name = ?, surnamereq""")`

Comment: And that gives me a `pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]COUNT field incorrect  (17) (SQLExecDirectW)')`

Comment: It might be a problem because im using python variables in the cursor.execute command, if so how should i have an input for the user to assign a variable to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the .execute method](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executesql-parameters) shows that the form of the method call is

**execute(sql, *parameters)**

and states that

> The optional parameters may be passed as a sequence, as specified by the DB API, or as individual values.

So, you could either do

```python
surnamereq = 'Thompson'
fname = 'Gord'
#
sql = "UPDATE money_spent SET first_name = ? WHERE last_name = ?"
params = (fname, surnamereq)
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

or

```python
surnamereq = 'Thompson'
fname = 'Gord'
#
sql = "UPDATE money_spent SET first_name = ? WHERE last_name = ?"
cursor.execute(sql, fname, surnamereq)
```

Note that the second approach is a pyodbc-specific extension to the [DB API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

Comment: What should i do if i get a `Previous SQL was not a query.` Error?

Comment: It does it when i use the `for row in cursor.fetchall():    print (row)` command at the end.